# Android: How to Know if any application is already installed in android device using adb?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I've to install an android app with package name like "com.xyz.game" using adb.
I want to automate the process using shell script. The process will be like if app is already installed, uninstall it(with command adb uninstall com.xyz.game) and install using "adb install game.apk" otherwise simple "adb install game.apk".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[**Update 2**]

Without using `grep`

`adb shell pm list packages [your.package.name]` as mentioned in the [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24711479/3025732) answer

[**Update**]

According to (also) correct answer below, try grep the result from pm list packages.

`adb shell pm list packages | grep com.your.app.package`

---

[**Original**]

If the application is already installed and if you try to install the same app again, adb will return with an error - `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]`. However, if you want to re-install the already installed app, then use `-r` parameter.

Ex:

```
adb install -r game.apk
```

Comment: Seems, -r flag is not working! It ignores installation if app is already installed.

Comment: Since I sometimes have to do testing with release and debug versions of my app which are signed with different certificates, I have to manually do the uninstall re-install to ensure it proceeds correctly.

Comment: That's bad solution. It's better to check with pm list packages command, as suggested in other answer.

Comment: Does the -r flag clean out the old app entirely before reinstalling? 

One of the main ways I use `adb uninstall` is if I suspect some cached data isn't getting cleaned up when redeploying a build and want to make sure I'm installing from a clean slate.

Comment: There is a better alternative without `grep` in one of the below answers.

Comment: With grep is better, because `list packages com package_name` will return an array with all packages which match partially to package_name (basically, as a grep). This can be a problem if you are  if looking for pre-installed apps, which can be a huge namespace. Case: I wanted to uninstall gmail, if present, (ie. com.google.android.gm) and my script tested for its presence with `adb shell pm list packages com.google.android.gm` before deleting it, but that returned three packages on my device, including com.google.android.gm. I fixed it with `| grep -w package_name`, with -w for word match.

Answer (score 18):

Try grep the result from pm list packages.

```
adb shell pm list packages | grep com.xyz.game
```

You may see the result if already installed.

```
package:com.xyz.game
```

Answer (score 15):

No need to use grep. Using following commands you can simply check if application is already exist or not.

Run ADB command

**adb shell pm list packages [your.package.name]**

If app is already installed then above command will return,

**package:[your.package.name]**

Else it won't return anything i.e. empty String.

Comment: You don't even need to write the entire exact name, so it's pretty much like a `grep` without typing `| grep`.

Comment: This was useful to me since grep returns with a non zero exit code if not found while this always returns with a zero exit code.

Answer (score 2):

Android 7.0 has introduced `cmd` (a new native code based) tool which allows to interact with Android services like `PackageManager` much faster than the old java bytecode based tools like `pm`. So for recent Android versions instead of `adb shell pm list packages <package.name.substring>` you should use

```
adb shell cmd package list packages <package.name.substring>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use First `adb shell` command if you are using adb otherwise you can use use root in same device by `su` command

Then, we can get path of installed apk files by their pkg names lets say in our case pkg name is com.tencent.ig

```
pm path com.tencent.ig | sed 's/package://'
```

**If app installed** : You will get the path to the apk file

**If app not installed** : You will get nothing

Previous answers are limited but by using above logic we can also use if statement easily like :

```
pkg=com.tencent.ig #Add pkg of your app only here
if [ -f $(pm path $pkg | sed 's/package://') ]
then 
echo "YES, app is installed"
#further commands if app is installed
else 
echo "NO, app is not installed"
#further commands if app not installed
fi
```

I think that will be much handy.

Comment: The `pm path` is better than `pm list` because `pm list <APP>` lists all package names CONTAINING `<APP>`; and `pm path` checks only for EXACT match.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account @Joel answer, just do it in one-liner

```sh
# uninstall only if exists
adb shell pm list packages | grep com.your.app.package && adb uninstall com.your.app.package
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine :

```
adb shell pm list packages your.package.name
```

Replace your.package.name with the required package name.

If app installed : You will get the path to the apk file

If app not installed : You will get nothing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).